# How do I remove specific character before and after single quote using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text string with single quotes, I'd like to remove the parenthesis before and after that single quotes by using regular expression. Could anyone suggest me Thank you.

For example,
I have `(name equal '('John')')` the result that I expect is `name equal '('John')'`

Comment: lets rule out the simple ways first `Trim( new char [] { ')' , '(' } )`

Comment: If your purpose is removing character before and after single quote, the result should be `(name equal''oh''`, can you explain why the first braket is removed the last but one isn't?

Answer (score 1):

// Using Regex

```
string input = "(name equal '('John')')";
Regex rx = new Regex(@"^\((.*?)\)$");

Console.WriteLine(rx.Match(input).Groups[1].Value);
```

// Using Substring method

```
String input= "(name equal '('John')')";
var result = input.Substring (1, input.Length-2);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Result:

```
name equal '('John')'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var replaced = Regex.Replace("(name equal '('John')')", @"\((.+?'\)')\)", "${1}");
```

The `Regex` class is in the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Use negative look behind `(?<! )` and negative look ahead `(?! )` which will stop a match if it encounters the `'`, such as

```
(?<!')\(|\)(?!')
```

The example explains it as a comment:

```
string pattern =
@"
(?<!')\(     # Match an open paren that does not have a tick behind it
|            # or
\)(?!')      # Match a closed paren tha does not have tick after it
";

var text = "(name equal '('John')')";

 // Ignore Pattern whitespace allows us to comment the pattern ONLY, does not affect processing.
var final = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

**Result**

> name equal '('John')'